# Does anyone know of any HTTP conformance testing suite around?

Tags: http, http-headers, serversocket

Me and my friends are building an HTTP server as an university project. But we have sort hit a snag when it came to the testing...

We have done the performance tests but we couldn't find any tool for the protocol conformance tests.

e.g.
I will run the software on a machine on the network and I want the software to make the requests and test the responses for validity, ie proper headers and stuff.

I don't care about the **body** of the response being sent as that is not a matter of serious concern.

Can anybody help me out here???

Regards
Binaek Sarkar
[Foundation](http://www.foundation.net.in/)

Comment: I don't think there is any such tool, and if there was what tests the tool?  You should just try using as many browsers and HTTP clients as you can.

Answer (score -1):

I know of two HTTP performance testing programs, [JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/) and [ab](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html). You should be able to extend JMeter to perform validity tests as well as pure performance metrics.